# Wicket Panel inside of a Fragment

Tags: java, html, wicket

Is it possible to add panel inside of a Fragment (fragment is used on a page which inherited other page), so I was using  tag also)?

Comment: I can't see why it shouldn't be possible. Have you run into a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. Here's a simple example:

Page:

```
package com.mycompany;

import org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Fragment;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;

public class HomePage extends WebPage {

    public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {
        super(parameters);

        Fragment fragment = new Fragment("fragment", "fragment-markup", this);

        fragment.add(new MyPanel("panel"));

        add(fragment);
    }
}
```

Page markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <body>
        <div wicket:id="fragment"/>

        <wicket:fragment wicket:id="fragment-markup">
            <div wicket:id="panel"/>
        </wicket:fragment>
    </body>
</html>
```

Panel:

```
package com.mycompany;

import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Panel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.Model;

public class MyPanel extends Panel {

    public MyPanel(String id) {
        super(id);

        add(new Label("hello", Model.of("Hello")));
        add(new Label("world", Model.of("World")));
    }

}
```

Panel markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <wicket:panel>
        <div wicket:id="hello"/>
        <div wicket:id="world"/>
    </wicket:panel>
</body>
</html>
```